# What formula do I use to divide the total opportunity amount over the program duration period showing the projected monthly revenue?

Tags: formula, formula-field

Closed won opportunity amount = $30k
Est start date field = 10/1/2023
Est end date field = 12/31/2023

Looking to display something similar to the below.
October monthly revenue = $10k
November monthly revenue = $10k
December monthly revenue = $10k

If that can't been accomplished then we'd like to see
$10k over 3 months

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please read [ask]. The general expectation here is that you've made an honest attempt to research and solve the issue on your own first. Showing us what you've tried is important, as is including plenty of details. Tell us more about your data model (you have an `Opportunity`, do you have any other SObjects that are related to your Opportunity?), show us a little mockup of what you want the result to look like.

Comment: As written, a formula field cannot handle this unless you literally want a result like `$10,000 per month over 3 months`. Also, if you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to help get you started. Specifically the [Formulas and Validations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic) and [Advanced Formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas) modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a formula, you could use the standard Opportunity schedule or '[Advanced Account Forecasting](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aaf_admin_parent_concept.htm&type=5)' as it's called now.

However, if you want to make your own solution,I would build out a new revenue object with a date and amount field and then generate the schedule based on math.

Total Price / EndDate-StartDate = amount per month.

You can generate the records with a flow.

Once you have some records it's really easy to create reports and dashboards to get a revenue per month/quarter/year.

Comment: Thank you, Dan - I will try both of your recommendations.

Comment: Report formulas (row-level and/or summary) will do it out of the box but don't need to go that far or Advanced Forecasting. Collab Forecasting is available out of the box with Sales Cloud, it has a myriad reports and it's auto-enabled for new orgs starting with Winter '24.

Comment: @identigral - thank you so much too